# Are these the files I need to reset my PC?

Tags: windows-10, usb, reset

Earlier this year someone prepared me a USB stick that I could use to reset my Windows 10 laptop. I did and it worked out great. Some time has passed, and I don't remember if I have done anything with the files in the meantime (like I accidentally deleted some or something).

This is what I have on the USB stick:

boot - (a folder with 9 items)
  efi - (a folder with two other folders in it)
  sources - (a folder with 181 items including about 10 folders)
  support - (a folder with another folder in it that has 22 items)

and then these files:

autorun.inf
  bootmgr
  bootmgr.efi
  setup.exe

Is there anything missing from the main files and directories that should be on it? I know I haven't messed with any of the files within the folders. I am just not sure whether I might have accidentally deleted some of the main.

Any tips on resetting Windows 10? It went well when I did it earlier this year when I was stuck on a blue screen. It's just that I don't remember it well. I don't want to find myself resetting my laptop and then missing an important file or something else I need.

Comment: By 'maps' do you mean folders / directories?

Comment: yes, I am sorry. I am actually Dutch, so there might be some mistakes in my text. I apologize.

Answer (score 0):

Format that USB stick and then [go here](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10) to download a fresh Windows 10 install to the USB. Once it's done boot from that USB and you will be able to do a repair where you keep your files.

Comment: Thanks! Gonna do that!

Comment: Please edit your answer, as it's currently factually inaccurate: In order to keep files and do a repair install, the Windows installer _must_ be ran while booted to Windows.  If you boot from the Windows Install Media, you can only do a clean install, not a repair install.